# i am trying to load the svg file but error is occurring (Error 102 Invalid start tag svg)

Tags: c#, svg, xamarin.android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg xmlns:osb="http://www.openswatchbook.org/uri/2009/osb"xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="10.2332in" height="11.252161in" viewBox="0 0 920.98797 1012.6946" id="svg2" version="1.1" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" sodipodi:docname="map.svg">
<defs id="defs4">
<linearGradient inkscape:collect="always" id="linearGradient6146">
<stop style="stop-color:#f2f2f2;stop-opacity:1;" offset="0" id="stop6148" />
<stop style="stop-color:#f2f2f2;stop-opacity:0;" offset="1" id="stop6150" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="linearGradient6140" osb:paint="solid">
<stop style="stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1;" offset="0" id="stop6142" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient inkscape:collect="always" xlink:href="#linearGradient6146" id="linearGradient6152" x1="757.7793" y1="1019.3268" x2="1032.8184" y2="1019.3268" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />
<linearGradient inkscape:collect="always" xlink:href="#linearGradient6146" id="linearGradient6154" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="757.7793" y1="1019.3268" x2="1032.8184" y2="1019.3268" />
</defs>
<sodipodi:namedview id="base" pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" inkscape:pageopacity="0.0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:zoom="0.41986485" inkscape:cx="665.09998" inkscape:cy="547.70001" inkscape:document-units="px" inkscape:current-layer="layer1" showgrid="false" units="in" fit-margin-left="-2" fit-margin-right="0" fit-margin-top="-1" fit-margin-bottom="0" inkscape:window-width="1366" inkscape:window-height="705" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-maximized="1" width="7.5in" height="9000in">
<inkscape:grid type="xygrid" id="grid3336" originx="-49.686342" originy="-348.02656" />
</sodipodi:namedview>
<metadata id="metadata7">
<rdf:RDF>
<cc:Work rdf:about="">
<dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
<dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
<dc:title>
</dc:title>
</cc:Work>
</rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g inkscape:label="Layer 1" inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="layer1" transform="translate(141.31935,-164.56211)">
<ellipse style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.47842932px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" id="path3349" cx="179.14752" cy="213.21657" rx="21.40518" ry="14.970306" />
<ellipse style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.47842932px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" id="path3349-5" cx="178.278" cy="548.51111" rx="21.40518" ry="14.970306" />
<path style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.18673158px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 178.10765,231.18477 c -2.42669,297.78248 -2.42669,297.78248 -2.42669,297.78248 l 0,-1.11949 2.42669,1.11949 0,0" id="path4175" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
<rect style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1" id="rect4182" width="157.72238" height="44.910931" x="-20.258638" y="180.71774" />
<rect style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1" id="rect4184" width="76.607979" height="37.4258" x="175.63919" y="74.562111" />
<rect style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1" id="rect4186" width="135.19063" height="52.396061" x="-90.107155" y="203.17317" />
<path style="fill:#000000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.05582392px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" d="m 148.7296,547.49026 -220.637008,0 0,0" id="path4288" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
<g style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:sans-serif;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" id="flowRoot4302" />
<ellipse style="fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1.47842932px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" id="path3349-1-0" cx="-87.03698" cy="863.2276" rx="21.40518" ry="14.970306" />
<rect style="fill:#f2f2f2;fill-opacity:1" id="rect4192-1-1-9-1" width="110.40601" height="60.835773" x="-976.95081" y="39.450497" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,0,0)" />
<rect style="fill:#f2f2f2;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:0.98224852" id="rect4192-1-1-9-6" width="110.40601" height="60.835773" x="-758.51715" y="-46.298756" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,0,0)" />
<rect style="fill:#f2f2f2;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-opacity:0.98224852" id="rect4192-1-1-9-6-0" width="110.40601" height="60.835773" x="-759.53809" y="53.483723" transform="matrix(0,-1,1,0,0,0)" />
</g>
</svg>
```

i am trying to load the svg file but error is occurring(Error 102 Invalid      start tag svg).The svg file and code is given i am storing svg file in Resources/values folder why this error is occurring

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

namespace App15
{
[Activity(Label = "App15", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
int count = 1;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
base.OnCreate(bundle);

// Set our view from the "main" layout resource
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
var doc = XDocument.Load("map.svg");
}
}
}
```

Comment: seems to be missing a space around here: 2009/osb"xmlns:dc i.e. after the "

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your environment. Xamarin manages SVG's differently to C#. I've never had to use SVG's in Android, but I've just found [this](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamsvg), which will help

Comment: But i am loading the same map.svg file in C# console application there is no problem with SVG start tag but when i try to load in c# android application the problem occure

Comment: yes both files are same the code is same @ Anonymouse

Comment: @AsadAhmad Please see updated answer. Apologies for misunderstanding your original question

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1' standalone='yes'?>
<Collection>
   <Book Id='1' ISBN='1-100000ABC-200'>
      <Title>Principle of Relativity</Title>
      <!-- Famous physicist -->      
      <Author>Albert Einstein</Author>
      <Genre>Physics</Genre>
   </Book>
   <Book Id='2' ISBN='1-100000ABC-300'>
      <!-- Also came as a TV serial -->
      <Title>Cosmos</Title>
      <Author>Carl Sagan</Author>
      <Genre>Cosmology</Genre>
   </Book>
   <!-- Add additional books here -->
</Collection>

Comment: The same problem is occurring with simple xml file i mention above plz check this problem again

Comment: Now he is saying that invalid start tag Collection

Comment: @AsadAhmad Both errors are complaining about the start tags... Try changing the encoding to UTF-8. If that doesn't work, remove the declaration. The XML loader may add them for you

Comment: The same problem with XML loader changing the encoding also not work @ Anonymouse

Comment: @AsadAhmad also for removing the declaration?

Comment: I just tested your SVG code straight in the browser, and it's valid (is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rhysoc/h29zwcs1/) what you wanted?). It must be to do with your Xamarin SVG.. Stick a break point on your doc variable and once it's executed copy the XML data from the internals and see if it's valid

Comment: no i also want to get attribute value and want to change attribute values but i am not getting my problem why xml file is not loading

Comment: Was the internal XML valid?